# Min length for SQL Name/Identifier in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I need to parse an SQL name for PostgreSQL, and to be sure it is always compliant.

I know that, for example, an SQL name/identifier can even consist of a single white space.

What I'm trying to find out is - is there a single use case within the entire PostgreSQL syntax where it is possible to pass in an empty `""` SQL name/identifier and still to be considered valid?

I want to know whether I should parse `""` as always invalid in PostgreSQL or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty quoted identifier is not valid as per the SQL standard.
You get the following error message when you try to create a table with `""`:

```
ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
```

And what would it identify anyways? There is no such thing like an identifier that identifies the empty identifier.

---

You can find out more about the syntax here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

> Quoted identifiers can contain **any** character, except the character
>   with code zero. (To include a double quote, write two double quotes.)
>   This allows constructing table or column names that would otherwise
>   not be possible, such as ones containing spaces or ampersands. The
>   length limitation still applies.

Comment: >And what would it identify anyways? - An empty identifier, I guess. The question was - is it something that's used anywhere in PostgreSQL?

Comment: And the answer was no.

Comment: Edited my answer to give a better explanation